# 3D max export to three.js with tiling

Tags: three.js

After exporting a 3D model from 3D max to three.js not work tiling. That is in itself not recorded json file settings for this feature

```
"materials": [
{
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName"  : "02 - Default",
"colorDiffuse"  : [0.5882, 0.5882, 0.5882],
"colorAmbient"  : [0.5882, 0.5882, 0.5882],
"colorSpecular"  : [0.9000, 0.9000, 0.9000],
"transparency"  : 1.0,
"specularCoef"  : 10.0,
"mapDiffuse"    : "rabica.png",
"vertexColors" : false
},
```

Comment: how are you exporting from max? Textures are not set to wrap and tile by default. You use `texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping` and `texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping` for wrapping and `texture.repeat.set( 4, 4 )`for tiling.

Comment: exporting using this script https://github.com/alteredq/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/max/ThreeJSExporter.ms

Just do not want to write repeat in callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the max exporter but had trouble with smoothing groups so do not use it. I may end up patching it at some stage in the future.
It seems to also not set the 'wrap' setting that you want.
After looking at the JSONLoader and Loader code it seems that it does handle wrap being set in the json file.
I think if you edit your json file manually so it looks as below, it may work.

```
"materials": [
{
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName"  : "02 - Default",
"colorDiffuse"  : [0.5882, 0.5882, 0.5882],
"colorAmbient"  : [0.5882, 0.5882, 0.5882],
"colorSpecular"  : [0.9000, 0.9000, 0.9000],
"transparency"  : 1.0,
"specularCoef"  : 10.0,
"mapDiffuse"    : "rabica.png",
"vertexColors" : false,
"mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"]
},
```

Though this is untested